# FOSUserBundle render multidimensional user data

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, render, fosuserbundle

I want to code an administration area for managing users.

For this I created an extra UserController in my AdminBundle (indexAction, newAction, editAction, deleteAction) for the indexAction I would like to render all users in a table.

To get all users the FOSUserBundle provides a method in the userManager:

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $users = $userManager->findUsers();

    print_r($users);

    return $this->render('KSRAdminBundle:User:index.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users,
    ));
}
```

My issue now is that I don't know how to render such a complex array.

I viewed the array through print_r and have no idea what to do

Best Regards,
Bodo Kaiser

Answer (score 1):

In your twig template file do something like this.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td> 
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td> 
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td> 
            <td>
                <a href="#">delete</a>
                <a href="#">edit</a>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```